# Ruby webcrawler gem

Tags: ruby, caching, web-crawler

I’m looking for a ruby gem that will continuously crawl my site, click on all links, and download all resources (including, for example all images referenced in srcset).

My ultimate goal is to keep the cache on my site perpetually warm.

Does such a gem exist? If not what’s the best way to accomplish this cache warming?

Comment: I don't know about a gem, but I did use `wget` for that in the past. See: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Comment: @katafrakt this is great! Do you know how I can use this to download images that are hosted on another domain (but not *everything* hosted on every domain)? It would be great to get all the images in the `srcset` too not just the `src`. Thoughts?

Comment: I think it works in wget2, which might be a bit harder to get that just installing from package manager - probably you'd need to compile it yourself. See: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2018-02/msg00001.html